# Enumeration type with some same values

Tags: c++

Why declaration of two enums type with same values in same block is not allowed in C++?

```
enum math_students {A,B,C};
enum comp_students {D,E,A}; // illegal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++03 `enum` doesn't have tighter type checking under their scopes. So both `math_students::A` and `comp_students::A` can be simply referred as `A`. That's why they are not allowed in the same scope.

To overcome that you can enclose them in `namespace` or `class`.

```
namespace math_students {
  enum { A, B, C };
}
namespace comp_students {
  enum { D, E, A };  // ok
}
```

In C++11 you can use `enum class` (it has tighter type checking; and they don't get converted to `int` implicitly).

```
enum class math_students {A,B,C};
enum class comp_students {D,E,A};  // ok
```

Comment: +1 for C++0x syntax, I strongly encourage people using C++0x to systematically migrate to *scoped enums*.

Comment: +1. Note that the *unnamed* enums would not work as template argument.

Comment: In the OP I could create a function accepting a math_students `foobar(math_students val)`.  Would this not be possible if I scoped them in a class or namespace?

Comment: @MattClarkson, you can definitely create a function accepting the enum `math_students`. The problem comes when you have another such enum and it has one or more value same as `math_students`. E.g. from OP `A` is common between `math_students` and `comp_students`. If you scope them inside `class` or `namespace` then this problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The values in an enum are not scoped. The members of an enum are accessed directly by their names. So if multiple enums have members with the same name, there will be a naming comflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the values by their names so it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can refer these values without specifying an enum name.

```
math_students student = A;
```

In your case this will be ambiguous, so, the compiler doesn't allow that.

Comment: You not only _can_ but you _have to_ refer to these values _without_ specifying the enum name (although some compilers support it anyhow).

Comment: @Stephan: Some of us are probably already using C++11 too much, where it is a *can* ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That is a reasonable change! Forget about my first comment!